# Can I use AWS route 53 and Cloudflare at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, amazon-route53, denial-of-service

Currently, I am using Route53 to manage my domains, subdomains etc.
But I want to add DDoS protection to my endpoints. So I want to use Cloudflare also. But I couldn't find a way to use two of them at the same time, can I put Cloudflare dos protection in front of the AWS r53?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You cannot use both Route53 and CloudFlare at the same time for your domain root DNS zone.

If you want to use Route53, you can:

- Use CloudFront to serve your entire website and then use the AWS DDoS protection (+ Amazon WAF for advanced ACLs).
- If you are using ELB w/ some EC2 instances, you can enable VPC Flow Logs and use Kinesis + Lambda to dynamically recognise DoS attacks and then ban the attacker IPs.

If you want to use Cloudflare to only protect a **subdomain**, you can delegate the management of a specific DNS "sub-"zone to CloudFlare.

For example:

- foobar.com is managed using a DNS zone of Route53
- attacked-subdomain.foobar.com is a subdomain that you want to protect with CloudFlare.

You can add the following records to your Route53 zone:

- attacked-subdomain.foobar.com NS nsXX.cloudflare.com
- attacked-subdomain.foobar.com NS nsYY.cloudflare.com

Then you can manage "attacked-subdomain.foobar.com" from your CloudFlare control panel.

It's not possible to help you more without having more details about you current infrastructure and the (D)Dos you're receiving. I hope I answered your question!

PS: I'd suggest to you to read the following whitepaper https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/DDoS_White_Paper_June2015.pdf

Comment: I am looking for a similar setup not to prevent DoS on subdomain but to lower a Cloudfront bill on a S3 bucket served via subdomain (route53). Your suggestion about creating NS records only for the subdomain is an interesting approach that we will test. Thanks!

Comment: Did this approach worked @RafaSashi?

Comment: @AnshulSahni It works, of course. The DNS protocol still works in the same way.

Comment: You can't use route53 with cloudflare? are you sure?